# arraylist return wrong index android

Tags: android, arraylist

i want to compare arraylist with a textview, when the value of arraylist and textview is match/same, i want to show the index of the arraylist..

**this is my code**

```
TextView namamenu2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nama_menu2);         
String nama_menu_upd = namamenu2.getText().toString();

for(MenuInputClass mic2 : results) {    
    String comp=mic2.getNama_menu();
    if(nama_menu_upd.equals(comp))
    {                               
        int compIndex=results.indexOf(comp);
        Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this,compIndex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                
    }       
}
```

**MenuInputClass**

```
public class MenuInputClass {

    private String nama_menu;
    private String jumlah_menu;

    public void setNama_menu(String nama_menu) {
        this.nama_menu=nama_menu;
    }

    public String getNama_menu() {
        return (nama_menu);
    }
}
```

when i show *compIndex* on Toast, its always show *-1*.But when i try to show the size of *result* , its show correct size.how can i fix this?

Comment: Use For loop , Foreach will not let you know that index unless you take a int counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try normal `For` loop instead `Foreach`, Foreach will not let you know that index unless you take a int counter.

With Normal `For`:

```
for(int i=0; i< results.size(); i++) {    
        MenuInputClass mic2= results.get(i);
        String comp=mic2.getNama_menu();
        if(nama_menu_upd.equals(comp))
        {                               
            Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this, i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                
        }       
    }
```

With `Foreach`:

```
int counter=0;
for(MenuInputClass mic2 : results) {    
    String comp=mic2.getNama_menu();
    if(nama_menu_upd.equals(comp))
    {                               
        Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this, counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                
    }  
     counter++;     
}
```